# Dataset to List with Linq

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, linq

I have a dataset with one table. I would like to convert this table in a list with Linq.

This code works fine:

```
var list = dsUniqueIds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(r => new { column1 = r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs") }).ToList();
```

But when I try to change the cast in a list like this:

```
List<string> list = dsUniqueIds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(r => new { column1 = r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs") })
                               .ToList();
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
```

I need this data in a list for an autocomplete on a textbox with jQuery.
To get the data to the jQuery I use JavaScriptSerializer and Serialize(list).
Serialize(list) doesn't work with a var. If I use a var I only get objects at the JavaScript.
This works fine if I fill the list with a foreach. But I want to try it with Linq and I have no idea why it won't work.

Anyone knows why this doesn't work?

Comment: because you are not selecting strings

Comment: you linq query returns a list of objects which have a property column1. This is not a List<string>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
r => new { column1 = r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs") }
```

That will create a new anonymous type with a property called `column1`.

try change it to.

```
r => r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `List<string>`, you should select `string`s, not objects of an anonymous type.

```
List<string> list = dsUniqueIds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`new { column1 = r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs") }` is creating a anonymous type with a single property `column1`.

You have `List<SomeAnonymousType>` you cannot convert it to `List<string>`. that's why compiler throws a compile time error.

Try this

```
List<string> list = dsUniqueIds.Tables[0]
                               .AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(r => r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs"))
                               .ToList();
```

Take a look at [Anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you write

```
List<string> list = dsUniqueIds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r=> r.Field<string>("UniqueIDs") }).ToList();
```

your code does not work because AnonymouseType!=string